# NameError: name '' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I am trying to make a script in Python that will conjugate Spanish verbs. This is my first time scripting with Python, so it may be a simple mistake. When I run the script, I input "yo tener" and receive an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 13, in    File "",
>   line 1, in  NameError: name 'yo' is not defined

- See more at: http://pythonfiddle.com/#sthash.bqGWCZsu.dpuf

  > ```
  > # Input pronoun and verb for conjugation.
  > text = raw_input()
  > splitText = text.split(' ')
  > conjugateForm = eval(splitText[0]) 
  > infinitiveVerb = eval(splitText[1]) 
  >
  > # Set the pronouns to item values in the list.
  > yo = 0
  > nosotros = 1
  > tu = 2
  > el = 3
  > ella = 3
  > usted = 3
  >
  > # Conjugations of the verbs.
  > tener = ["tengo", "tenemos", "tienes", "tiene", "tienen"]
  > ser = ["soy", "somos", "eres", "es", "son"]
  > estar = ["estoy", "estamos", "estas", "esta", "estan"]
  >
  > # List of all of the infinitive verbs being used. Implemented in the following "if" statement.
  > infinitiveVerbs = [tener, ser, estar]
  >
  > # Check to make sure the infinitive is in the dictionary, if so conjugate the verb and print.
  > if infinitiveVerb in infinitiveVerbs:
  >     print("Your conjugated verb is: " + infinitiveVerb[conjugateForm])
  > ```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function, you're evaluating its arguments as a Python statement. I don't think that's what you want to do...

If you're trying to get the pronoun into the `conjugateForm` variable, and the verb into the `infinitiveVerb` variable, just use:

```
conjugateForm, infinitiveVerb = text.split()
```

By default, `split()` splits on whitespace, so the `' '` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Better than to allow the user access to your program's internals is to store the keys as strings as well. Then you don't need `eval` at all.

```
pronouns = { "yo": 0, "nosotros": 1, "tu"; 2, "el": 3, "ella": 3, "usted": 3 }
```

and similarly

```
verbs = { "tener": [ "tengo", "tenemos", ... ],
    "ser": [ "soy", "somos", ... ],
    ... }
```

Now you can just use the user's inputs as keys into the two dictionaries.

(I don't know if there's a separate tradition for Spanish, but a common arrangement is to list the singular forms first, then the plurals, both in first, second, and third person. You seem to be missing the second and third person plural.)

Comment: Also, `eval` is a security risk. Consider what could happen if the user would type `os.system('/home/hack.sh')` as input to your program.