# NameError: name 'main' is not defined - indentation

Tags: python-3.x, program-entry-point

I am new to python and this question has been asked before

1. [nameError name is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492657/nameerror-name-is-not-defined)
2. [NameError: name '' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558934/nameerror-name-is-not-defined)
3. [NameError name 'Views' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404491/nameerror-name-views-is-not-defined)

but i have a different situation, this is my program

```
class student:    
    def address(self):
        print('address is mumbai')

    def contact(self):
        print('email : foo@yahoo.com')

    def main(self):
        _student=student()
        _student.address()
        _student.contact()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i dont know if it is my indentation that is causing problem or it has something to do with the scope of the method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main` is a method inside of the class `student`, so you need to change where `main` is defined.

```
class student:    
    def address(self):
        print('address is mumbai')

    def contact(self):
        print('email : foo@yahoo.com')

def main():
    _student=student()
    _student.address()
    _student.contact()
```